# How can I rename an NFS share as seen in Dolphin?

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, nfs, dolphin

How can I rename an NFS share as seen in file managers?

By default it named the share the NFS volume root location + IP info.

Seems to work in `Nautilus` but not `Dolphin`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply unmmount it

```
sudo umount /mnt/nfs/nfs_root+ip_name
```

and remount again with the name you want:

```
sudo mount 192.168.1.42:/nfs_folder /home/user/MY_WANTED_NAME
```

If you want to do it automatically (at system startup) add following lines to
`/etc/fstab` file:

```
192.168.1.42:/nfs_folder /home/user/my_fav_name nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
```

But in this case your mounting point (directory `home/user/my_wanted_name`) **should already be created** at the moment of startup.

Comment: Hmm. Sounded like a silly question but it doesn't appear to work that way in `Dolphin` while it does in `Nautilus`. Or are you saying it needs to be mounted, unmounted, and then mounted again for a name to take effect?

Comment: Exactly. Your folder seems to be mounted automatically by system, so you should reload it again. Simpler solution for this is to use `mount -o` syntax which remount already mounted shares. See man-page of `mount` for details.

Comment: Still not working on `Dolphin`.